# TypeScript React setState is not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component with input like this

```
import * as React from 'react'

import { InputNumber, Button } from 'antd'

interface IProps {
  value: number
}

interface IState {
  value: number
}

class ConfirmInput extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  public readonly state = {
    value: 0
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps = ({ value }: IProps) => ({ value })

  public render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <InputNumber
          value={this.state.value}
          formatter={value => `$ ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')}
          parser={(value): any => value && value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, '')}
          onChange={(value: number) => {
            console.log('value', value)
            this.setState({ value })
          }}
        />
        <Button
          onClick={() => console.log('this.state.value', this.state.value)}
          type="primary"
        >
          Bid
        </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ConfirmInput
```

on the `InputNumber` I have on change and that gets a number as a value, however `this.setState` doesn't change the value.
There are no compiler errors and everythings seems to be ok with types.
What am I missing in here?

Comment: Use the setstate callback function to print the console object to see whether the object is updated.

Comment: Your `getDerivedStateFromProps` method [is called every time the state changes](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), and it is overwriting the state from the props.  What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ImeshChandrasiri yup

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I want to pass `onConfirm` function as a prop then on button click pass the state value to it. The component gets its initial value from the props as well.

Comment: What should happen if the number in the state has been changed and then the number in the props changes?  Do you reset the state?  The answer to this will determine what you need to write in the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen if the props changes it should get the props value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to store the original value in the state so that your `getDerivedStateFromProps` implementation can overwrite the current value only when the prop changes.  This should hopefully work (not tested):

```
interface IState {
  value: number
  origValue: number
}

class ConfirmInput extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  // ...
  static getDerivedStateFromProps = (props: IProps, state: IState) =>
    (props.value != state.origValue ? { origValue: props.value, value: props.value } : {})
  // ...
}
```